# BluemixのNode.jsサンプルアプリが正しく動かない

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluemix

Bluemix初心者です。
今チュートリアルを見ながらこのサンプルのアプリをBluemixで動かそうとしています。
https://hub.jazz.net/project/ibmdevopsservices/Sentiment%20Analysis%20App/overview

プロジェクトをFORKしてBluemixにデプロイしました。デプロイは成功してNode.js環境ができましたがアプリが正しく動いていないようでWebブラウザの表示が更新されません。検索語がよくないのかと思って他の単語を指定しても結果は変わりませんでした。これはどうすればよろしいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter APIキーが有効でないためと考えられます。
サンプルアプリケーション内で指定されているTwitter APIキーを、ご自分で取得されたキーに置き換えてください。

もしTwitter APIキーをお持ちでないのであれば、下記URLのTwitter Developer Centerより取得してください。
https://dev.twitter.com/

APIキーの取得方法は詳しい解説ページがあると思うので検索していただければと思いますが、上記URLにTwitterのアカウントでサインイン→「Manage Your Apps」をクリック→「Create New App」をクリック→必要事項を入力という流れでキーが発行されます。

ここで以下の4つの情報をメモします。

-API key
-API secret
-Access token
-API secret

これら4つをサンプルアプリケーションのapp.jsの22行目以降のシングルクォーテーション内に順に上書きします。

```
    var tweeter = new twitter({
    consumer_key: 'BFqTaQ24kn1mpdy7BmJZZkAgM',
    consumer_secret: 'XhHbGzHzVj0UG5WRApSryl32Ysqo8Ig1BHwdMgIOSjRny4DV0S',
    access_token_key: '2495803602-gx2KrW2YE0OYrBh1pLhpAzggDsae8wdEm3tWlwU',
    access_token_secret: 'qWaS4UoSOcdX1C1AvgYCJ8KWbCypBXyi1xqkD8ktLa3xA'
});
```

これで改めてBluemixにデプロイし直せば正しく動くものと思います。
試してみてください。